# How to set a base image for Testcontainer for Quarkus tests for native library support?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, quarkus, maven-surefire-plugin, testcontainers

I am using Quarkus to write a Java application that processes IP camera streams and infers with deep learning models. For this application, I am using native libraries (.so files located in /opt/) and their corresponding Java Wrappers. Also, I need to run a License client in order to use said SDKs.

I got everything setup on my local machine and mvn quarkus:dev is working fine.
However, after upgrading from Quarkus 2.16.5.Final to 3.2.0.Final, the tests are not working anymore.

Before `mvn test` did work, `mvn quarkus:test` did not work, crashing the JVM while initalizing the native SDK with JNI.

```
com.sun.jna.Native.invokeLong(Lcom/sun/jna/Function;JI[Ljava/lang/Object;)
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;ZI)Ljava/lang/Object;+243

j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+271

j  com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+390

j  jdk.proxy5.$Proxy152.FRInitialize(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/sun/jna/NativeLong;+16 jdk.proxy5
```

After upgrading Quarkus, `mvn test` does also not work.

Disabling all devservices do not use Testcontainers does not work (crashing the JVM).
Using Testcontainers does not work because it is either crashing the JVM as well or I receive a license error, because obviously the license client is not present in the container.

**So, how do I set a base-image for the test-containers used by Quarkus (that includes all libraries, dependencies, etc)?** In fact, I am already building a Container for deployment that includes every dependency and is working fine.

I am completely lost and the Quarkus documentation is not helping.

I tried setting:
`quarkus.test.container-image quarkus.jib.jvm-image`
different surefire-plugin version (3.0.0-M7, 3.1.2)

But `mvn quarkus:test` is still using `testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1`

If I run `mvn test` and use the latest surefire-plugin version 3.1.2, I get:

```
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 134
Corrupted channel by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM
```

And a Buffer Overflow error.